# Have child divs fill parent div with set proportions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to create a function with jQuery/javascript that would fill a parent div with children divs of random sizes that add up the size of the parent.

For example, 10 child divs to fill a container div with proportions 1200px x 600px

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- 10 child divs with random height and width. -->
</div>
```

Comment: So when you say random, is that the full range from 0 to max container width/height? Or did you have in mind an "ideal" range?

Comment: I guess there would have to be SOME parameters, (maybe mins of 50px, maxes of 300px) so they'd be visible but  not overwhelming.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a function which splits a rectangle into two subrectangles, and recursivelly split these.

- When splitting a rectangle into two parts, if it must contain an even number N of subrectangles, each part will have N/2 subrectangles.
- When splitting a rectangle into two, if it must contain an odd number of leaf subrectangles, the bigger part will have one more child than the other.

```js
function fillWithChilds(el, N) {
  function rand(n) {
    /* weight=100 means no random
       weight=0 means totally random  */
    var weight = 50;
    return Math.floor(weight*n/2+n*(100-weight)*Math.random())/100;
  }
  function main(N, x, y, hei, wid) {
    if(N < 1) return;
    if(N === 1) {
      var child = document.createElement('div');
      child.className = 'child';
      child.style.left = x + 'px';
      child.style.top = y + 'px';
      child.style.width = wid + 'px';
      child.style.height = hei + 'px';
      el.appendChild(child);
      return;
    }
    var halfN = Math.floor(N/2);
    if(wid > hei) {
      var newWid = rand(wid);
      if(2*newWid > wid) halfN = N-halfN;
      main(halfN, x, y, hei, newWid);
      main(N-halfN, x+newWid, y, hei, wid-newWid);
    } else {
      var newHei = rand(hei);
      if(2*newHei > hei) halfN = N-halfN;
      main(halfN, x, y, newHei, wid);
      main(N-halfN, x, y+newHei, hei-newHei, wid);
    }
  }
  main(N, 0, 0, el.clientHeight, el.clientWidth);
}
fillWithChilds(document.getElementById('wrapper'), 11);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #ccf;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px
}
.child {
  background: #cfc;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The distributing will be a pain. I think there's a jQuery library out there that handles some of it... I'll poke around. This is a pretty fun problem, though.

Here's what I've go so far. It's a bit sparse.

http://jsfiddle.net/twPQ7/2/

The part that attempts to determine how many more components it should build is the rough part. I'm trying to keep this down to as few loops as possible:

```
var containerSize = getContainerSize();
var elementWidth = 0;
var elementHeight = 0;

// width
while (elementWidth < containerSize.x)
{
    var size = generateElement();
    elementWidth += size.x;
    elementHeight += size.y;        
}
// height, if not already full
while (elementHeight < containerSize.y)
{
    var size = generateElement();
    elementWidth += size.x;
    elementHeight += size.y; 
}
```

Cleaned it up a bit. Check the fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/twPQ7/2/

```
// determine the size of the container
var containerSize = getContainerSize();
var elementWidth = 0;
var elementHeight = 0;

// iteratively generate elements until we've hit the width of the container
while (elementWidth < containerSize.x)
{
    var size = generateElement();
    elementWidth += size.x;

    // keep track of the tallest element.
    if (size.y > elementHeight) elementHeight = size.y;
}
// iteratively generate elements until we've hit the height of the container
while (elementHeight < containerSize.y)
{
    var size = generateElement();
    elementHeight += size.y; 
}
```